# Deciphering graph theory statement/notation.

Tags: graph-theory, notation, directed-graphs

I'm trying to understand the following statement (found in [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.8037.pdf) paper):

> For every strongly connected component S ⊆ E of the digraph (A, E), if |S| = 1 then there is a loop incident to the node in S.

where $A$ is a set of nodes and $E$ is a set of edges of a digraph.

1. Does $|S|$ mean "number of edges in the SCC", or could it be something else ? The paper doesn't introduce this notation.
2. If so, then the only SCC with $|S|=1$ has to be a single node with a self referencing arc, like $A\to A$. Right?
3. I guess one or both the above aren't true, otherwise it seems trivial that any node with a self-referential arc must have a loop, which would be that self-referential arc itself. Or would this not classify as a "loop"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|S|$ is the number of nodes. So it is just saying that if the SCC has only one node, then there is a loop at that node.

This is clear from the next couple of lines which mention an SCC $\{k\}$ and then talk about nodes other than $k$. I assume the $S\subseteq E$ is a typo.

Comment: Thanks. So is this just a somewhat convoluted way of saying "If a node has one self-referencing arc, then it must be part of a loop" ?

Comment: No, it's saying that if an SCC only has one node, that node has a loop. You can in general have a single-node SCC without a loop, for example a vertex with no arcs coming in, but according to the paper this can't happen if there is an equilibrium.

Comment: I see I confused things by using "vertex" to mean "node", will edit.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. What is the difference between "for every node" and "for every scc with size 1"?

Comment: @mvc Some SCCs are larger than a single node, and nodes in those SCCs aren't covered by the requirement.

Comment: For example, if there are three nodes forming a directed triangle, those nodes don't form SCCs of size $1$, so don't have to have loops.

Comment: Ah I think I see my mistake. I was considering that "every SCC in the triangle A->B->C->A" would be the set {{A,B,C},{A},{B},{C}}, where each node would count as a "degenerate" SCC. I see I was overthinking it. Thanks a lot for the help!